# How do I pass the date period to the apex method?

Tags: apex, soql, date, js-controller

I need to pass the date period "from" "to" from the js controller to the apex method in order to extract a list of values from the database.

**//cmp**

```
...
    <aura:attribute name="dateFrom" type="Date"/>
    <aura:attribute name="dateTo" type="Date"/>
...
```

**//js**

```
getDataForThePeriod : function(component, helper){
        let dateFrom = component.get("v.dateFrom");
        let dateTo = component.get("v.dateTo");
        if(dateFrom != '' && dateTo != '' && dateFrom < dateTo){
            //here I need to contact apex to make a request for data for the period
        }
    },
```

**//apxc**

//Date__c - this is the field of the object for which I want to get data for a certain period.

//Also, should the method accept a single variable in the form of a period (String?) or should there be two of them (Date type)?

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Exchange_Rate__c> getListExchangeRates (...){
        String currencys = converter(getListFieldsCurrenciesForRequest());
        return Database.query('SELECT Date__c, Base_Currency__c, ' + currencys + ' FROM Exchange_Rate__c WHERE Date__c...');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly pass date as a parameter in apex. And query like below code example.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Exchange_Rate__c> getListExchangeRates (Date toDate , Date fromDate){
        String currencys = converter(getListFieldsCurrenciesForRequest());
        return Database.query('SELECT Date__c, Base_Currency__c, ' + currencys + ' FROM Exchange_Rate__c WHERE Date__c >= :fromDate and Date__c <= :toDate ');
    }
```

Comment: I fixed the apex method, but now I get: `System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found 'dateTo'`. My js: `let action = component.get('c.getListExchangeRatesForThePeriod'); action.setParams({"dateFrom" : dateFrom, "dateTo" : dateTo});`

Comment: problem is in your query make sure to add colon WHERE Date__c >= :fromDate and Date__c <= :toDate

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed this point in the "DateTo" condition of the apex method and thought the problem was related to the js method. Thank you for your help!